# Terraform: Convert a large number of data sources to resources without importing

Tags: resources, terraform

Is there some way to convert a data source to a resource after creating a large number of them manually without having to first importing it and/or destroying the data source first?

If I destroy them just now, their dependencies will also need to be destroyed and I very much need them to stay put (to the point where I've added the `lifecycle { prevent_destroy = true }` to them).

I can see a way of doing this by just importing them one at a time after converting the data source to resources, but is there some automated way?

Example:

```
data "aws_sns_topic" "example" {
  count = "${length(topics)}"
  name = "${topics[count.index]}"
}
```

But I now want to have them as resources:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "example" {
  count = "${length(topics)}"
  name = "${topics[count.index]}"
  name_prefix = "pref-${topics[count.index]}"
}
```

And I see no way of doing this without performing a ton of manual import steps. Is there some way to perform a convert-to-resource-step?

Comment: Can you explain a bit further what you want here? Providing your code and explaining why it doesn't do what you want would help a lot because right now it doesn't seem to make much sense. Data sources are for fetching information from your provider while resources actually create things. Moving between them doesn't make any sense really.

Comment: I've added an example to the post, thank you!

Comment: That doesn't make any sense still. You have some data sources that are looking up some preexisting resources and you want to change them into resources? How would that even work?

Comment: I have some data-sources that already exist, meaning when I run `terraform apply` it all works great. Now I want to change the data sources to resources, but I don't see a clever way of doing it apart from performing a `terraform import` in every single one of them. Is it more clear now?